# Trying to set slideToggle to be above background/slider

Tags: javascript, background-image, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make a simple landing page for a new product. The idea is to have a full page slider in background, with a toggle/panel that will slide down overtop of the image and reveal content.

I'm using this slide panel - http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html
And Superslider which can be found at nicianbox.github.is/supersliders

And this is my result, the issue is that the toggle/panel pushes the slider down rather then slides overtop of it. Can anyone see a solution? Z-index does do me any good.

http://robinwkurtz.com/MMC/index_8.html
And with just a background image (Worst case if the slider isn't possible) can be seen on index_6.html

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
  });
 });
```

Many thanks!

Comment: .panel { position:absolute; width:100% }

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't achieve what i was going for. It brought the panel over the image but left the "header" and controls at the top, rendering them unusable. I'll see if I can work around that by wrapping it or something.

Answer (score 0):

With Malk's anwser, I wrapped the toggle elements and applied the css... It works like a dream. Thanks!